# Cannot pass returned values from function to another function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My goal is to have a small program which checks if a customer is approved for a bank loan. It requires the customer to earn > 30k per year and to have atleast 2 years of experience on his/her current job. The values are get via user input. I implemented regexs to validate the input to be only digits  without any strigns or negatives, nor 0.

But the 3rd function `asses_customer` is always executing the else part. I think everytime the parameters are either None, either 0

here's the source code:

```
import sys
import re
import logging
import self as self


class loan_qualifier():

    # This program determines whether a bank customer
    # qualifies for a loan.

    def __init__(self): #creates object
        pass

def main():

        salary_check()
        work_exp_check()
        asses_customer(salary = 0, years_on_job = 0)


def salary_check():

        input_counter = 0  # local variable

        # Get the customer's annual salary.
        salary = raw_input('Enter your annual salary: ')
        salary = re.match(r"(?<![-.])\b[1-9][0-9]*\b", salary)

        while not salary:

            salary = raw_input('Wrong value. Enter again: ')
            salary = re.match(r"(?<![-.])\b[1-9][0-9]*\b", salary)

            input_counter += 1

            if input_counter >= 6:
                print ("No more tries! No loan!")
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                return salary


def work_exp_check():

        input_counter = 0 #local variable to this function

        # Get the number of years on the current job.
        years_on_job = raw_input('Enter the number of ' +
                                 'years on your current job: ')
        years_on_job = re.match(r"(?<![-.])\b[1-9][0-9]*\b", years_on_job)

        while not years_on_job:

            years_on_job = raw_input('Wrong work experience. Enter again: ')
            years_on_job = re.match(r"(?<![-.])\b[1-9][0-9]*\b", years_on_job)

            input_counter += 1

            if input_counter >= 6:
                print ("No more tries! No loan!")
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                return years_on_job

def asses_customer(salary, years_on_job):

        # Determine whether the customer qualifies.
        if salary >= 30000.0 or years_on_job >= 2:

            print 'You qualify for the loan. '
        else:
            print 'You do not qualify for this loan. '

# Call main()
main()
```

Comment: Just FYI, [people don't like when you put stuff like "HELP" or "URGENT" in your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/7662085).

Comment: will keep it in mind next time, thanks

Comment: You only ever call `asses_customer` with `asses_customer(salary = 0, years_on_job = 0)`; what do you expect the parameters to be?  (Also, the verb "assess" is spelled with two S's at the end; one S gives you a bunch of donkeys.)

Comment: can you help me to do it the right way?

Comment: please fix your indention.

Comment: where exactly??

Comment: 2 of your `else` statements do not align with the `if` statements. Your data inside of your functions are indented way to far

Comment: @Mike-SMT unless those are supposed to be `while-else` blocks?

Comment: @AdamSmith thats fine however the functions still need their indention fixed.

Comment: Also you have `class loan_qualifier():` but you have nothing in it. Are you trying to write this all in a class? and what is `import self as self`?

Comment: fixed them but it didn't change anything

Comment: the import was due to auto-completed suggestion by pycharm, yes the class seems redundant... actually I have some dificulties undersanding it - I am new to python (have some java background)

Comment: I didnt say it would change anything. You should always make sure to have accurate indention for a few reason. It can be confusing to how your code is actually formatted compared to what is seen in your question and it can also cause problems with code execution.

Comment: @Mike-SMT functions were not inaccurately indented, only non-standardly indented. The indentation was valid Python code, even if it wasn't PEP8 ;)

Comment: @Mike-SMT can you give me a suggestion about how to fix it please?

Comment: Well your code seams over complicated to me. It would be much simpler to write a smaller code to get the same results. No need for the regex or any of your imports really.

Comment: yep, I agree... I took an example from a book and got drifted away. I heavily tested the regex and the first 2 functions work good, only can't cope with the passing the parameters to the last function

Comment: It's not hyper-relevant to your question, but the word is assess, asses-customer has a somewhat different meaning haha.

Answer (score 2):

You have stated:

> It requires the customer to earn > 30k per year and to have at least 2 years of experience on his/her current job.

We can write some simple statements that request a number and if a number is not given then ask for that number again.

The following code is a very simple approach to achieving that goal.

```
class Loan_Checker():
    def __init__(self):
        self.salary = 0
        self.years_on_job = 0

        self.request_salary()
        self.request_years()
        self.check_if_qualified()

    def request_salary(self):
        x = raw_input('Enter your annual salary: ')
        try:
            self.salary = int(x)
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
            self.request_salary()

    def request_years(self):
        x = raw_input('Enter the number of years on your current job: ')
        try:
            self.years_on_job = int(x)
        except:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
            self.request_years()

    def check_if_qualified(self):
        if self.salary >= 30000 and self.years_on_job >= 2:
            print 'You qualify for the loan. '
        else:
            print 'You do not qualify for this loan. '

Loan_Checker()
```

Comment: THanks mate, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code, and I've refactored it to use the class structure you seemed to want to imply.

```
import sys
import re
import logging

class loan_qualifier():

    # This program determines whether a bank customer
    # qualifies for a loan.

    def __init__(self): #creates object
        self.salary = self.salary_check()
        self.years_on_job = self.work_exp_check()


    def salary_check(self):

        input_counter = 0  # local variable

        # Get the customer's annual salary.
        salary = None

        while salary is None:
            if input_counter >= 6:
                print ("No more tries! No loan!")
                sys.exit(0)
            elif input_counter >= 1:
                print ("Invalid salary.")

            salary = raw_input('Enter your salary: ')
            salary = re.match(r"(?<![-.])\b[1-9][0-9]*\b", salary).group(0)
            input_counter += 1

        # broke out of loop, so valid salary
        return salary




    def work_exp_check(self):

        input_counter = 0 #local variable to this function

        # Get the number of years on the current job.
        years_on_job = None

        while years_on_job is None:
            if input_counter >= 6:
                print ("No more tries! No loan!")
                sys.exit(0)
            elif input_counter >= 1:
                print ("Invalid year amount")

            years_on_job = raw_input('Enter the number of years at your current job: ')
            years_on_job = re.match(r"(?<![-.])\b[1-9][0-9]*\b", years_on_job).group(0)

            input_counter += 1

        # broke out of loop, so valid years_on_job
        return years_on_job



    def assess_customer(self):

        # Determine whether the customer qualifies.
        if int(self.salary) >= 30000.0 and int(self.years_on_job) >= 2:
            print 'You qualify for the loan. '
        else:
            print 'You do not qualify for this loan. '

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lq = loan_qualifier()
    lq.assess_customer()
```

Some of the errors fixed include the way you were calling assess_customer initially (you were assigning 0's to both values in the function call), as well as the spelling of assess :p.  Your condition in assess_customer should also have been an and instead of an or (you wanted both conditions to be true for them to qualify, not for either condition to be true).

You actually don't even really need to do the:

```
self.salary = self.salary_check()
self.years_on_job = self.work_exp_check()
```

lines.  You could just directly assign the class variables in the functions (i.e. instead of returning, just set self.salary = blah in salary_check). That's kind of a personal choice thing though.  I think this makes it clear.

Hopefully this is all clear to you.  Let me know if you have any questions.  The code can be called by simply typing python NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE.py.

Edit: I didn't realize how broken the salary and years checks were, the new code should fix them.

Edit: Fixed the regex results in this version. My bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I will review it in details tomorrow (it's 3:12 in the morning in here and I am going to fall asleep on the laptop. WiIll update you tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. I just updated it to perform the checks for salary and years_on_the_job correctly.  I didn't realize they weren't rejecting the bad cases earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saedeas, reviewed your changes at now it seems a lot better. I only face the following problem - now the 'assess_customer' function always prints the first statement, no matter of the input. I can't debug it (any ideas why I can't debug with breakpoints?
Also the last rows:
'if __name__ == "__main__":
    lq = loan_qualifier()
    lq.assess_customer()'

I believe this is calling a main function or sth? where it is? I am curious, thanks :)

Comment: Update: I debugged with pdb,set_trace() but I don't understand why it always executes the first print statement (the if clause is always true) something is wrong in here.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see this comment. I forgot I had added in the .group(0) portion on my test code and not here.  That gets the actual string result from the regex.  I then cast it to an int in the check.  The code works now.

Answer (score 0):

In this fragment you pass third function always `salary = 0` and `years_on_job = 0`

Try this way:

```
salary = salary_check()
years_on_job = work_exp_check()
asses_customer(salary, years_on_job)
```

Comment: yeah, tried it but I get this error when I reach the function:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:    assess_customer(salary, years_on_job)
NameError: global name 'salary' is not defined