# int() and float() methods in python - how to enhance program to not allow '0' or negative digits?

Tags: python

Hello in relation to my previous question(the link below). Now my two functions use raw_input and validate to be a valid int/float. I don't want zeros (0) and negative numbers to be allowed but I can't seem to accomplish it.
Code snippet:

```
def salary_check(self):

    input_counter = 0  # local variable

    self.salary = None

    while not self.salary:

        sal = raw_input('Enter your salary: ')

        try:
            self.salary = float(sal)

        except:
            print ("Invalid salary amount!")
            if input_counter >= 6:
                print ("No more tries! No loan!")
                sys.exit(0)

        input_counter += 1

    return self.salary
```

[Cannot pass returned values from function to another function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373683/)

Comment: If your fine with `int` rather than `float`, you can simply check `if sal.isnumeric() && int(sal) > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
try:
    self.salary = float(sal)
```

To this:

```
try:
    self.salary = float(sal)
    if self.salary <= 0:
            raise Exception
```

It will go into your except if it is zero or negative. Your other code already catches it.

Edit: Sorry was on my phone doing this. There this should work right now.

Comment: `assert self.salary > 0, 'must enter positive salary'`

Comment: @acuschner, thanks this works but only for 0 input. If it is negative it is still the same

Comment: I edited it. Sorry about that. I was on my phone and didn't put the IF statement in. Make sure you do <=, if you do just < it won't catch 0

Answer (score 2):

This could be a good time to make use of an `assert` statement. `assert`s evaluate a Boolean, and if false, it throws an `AssertionError`. I sugggest this because your code already has a `try`/`except` block in the area in question, so this saves you from extra `if...else...` statements.

The relevant part of your code:

```
while not self.salary:

    sal = raw_input('Enter your salary: ')

    try:
        self.salary = float(sal)
        assert self.salary > 0

    except:
        print ("Invalid salary amount!")
        self.salary = ""  #This is important so that your while condition holds true; 
                          #the empty string will evaluate till false, 
                          #clearing the 0 or negative number inputted
        if input_counter >= 6:
            print ("No more tries! No loan!")
            sys.exit(0)

    input_counter += 1
```

This way, when someone enters `0` or a number less than `0`, it throws an `AssertionError`, which is caught by your `except`

Comment: Thanks but when I enter 0 - it works properly, it prompts for input again and increments the counter until sys.exit. but if I enter a negative value it just prints the statement in the except clause and leaves the loop

Comment: I added another line that should prevent that, sorry I didn't think about it sooner. What was happening was that the value was getting set to a negative number, so even though it said "Invalid Salary Amount" it still broke the while loop. The `self.salary = ""` in the except block should fix that.

Comment: You really shouldn't use assertions unless it is for debugging, assertion statements can be skipped by the interpreter by passing the `-O` flag, e.g. `python -O myscript.py`. Use a real exception.

Comment: That's what I get for learning Python in a classroom lol, our teacher was all about using assertions for these kinds of things and never once mentioned that they could be skipped command line. We had entire assignments dedicated to adding dozens of assertions to code like this. Thanks for the information!

Comment: I mean, by no means is it bad to use assertions for debugging code, but in real production systems, you should probably be defining your own exception types, or using appropriate built-in exceptions, and **never** have bare-except clauses, or the barely less-bad `except Exception:`

Comment: The bare-except clause I don't personally ever use, I just wanted to make my suggestions to the code the least invasive as possible so I didn't change the bare except that the OP already had. As for assertions, I still know that there are good debugging reasons to use them as well, but this idea that I'm putting an except to limit user input... and the user can just ignore it by giving the program the -O flag upon execution... well that's something that I would have thought was not only acceptable to do, but good style, and now I see it is actually quite dumb.

Comment: Thank you all for your  time.
@Davy M thanks a lot - this is the solution I was looking for! Can you explain me the intention of self.salary "" in details? I believe it is reseting the variable?

Comment: The reason for the `self.salary = ""` is included because of your while condition. You say `while not self.salary:` which evaluates to true when `self.salary` is empty or null. When the person inserts a negative or zero to `self.salary = float(sal)` , `self.salary` gets that negative or zero stored in that variable, so when the loop tries to evaluate `not self.salary:` , it comes back with false and your loop exits. However, if we reset `self.salary = ""` , this will make the `not self.salary:` evaluate to true, and your while loop will continue.